# What is expected format for opencv morphologyEx(..., borderValue) argument?

Tags: opencv, python

I would like to pad my grayscale image with white border for purpose of morphological close in opencv (in Python). Documentation does not really tell what the function needs. I have been trying following two examples to no avail:

```
smooth_mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, 
                               borderValue=mask.max())

smooth_mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, 
                               borderValue=np.array([mask.max()]))
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Scalar value for argument 'borderValue' is not numeric
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out to be plain scalar python `int` that solved the problem, not `np.uint8` as in the input image.